# django model, using a value from another object as a choice

Tags: python, django

im trying to use a value from another object as a choice as per below. So i will have a pre defined set list of maintenance types to choose from in the impact field. when i try to create this model i get the error

```
[root@network-tools infternal]# python manage.py makemigrations maintenance
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
maintenance.Maintenance.Impact: (fields.E004) 'choices' must be an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple).
```

model config

```
class MaintenanceType(models.Model):
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
                verbose_name = "Planned Maintenance Types"
                verbose_name_plural = "Planned Maintenance Types"

class Maintenance(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Impact = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=MaintenanceType)
    Description = models.TextField()
    StartTime = models.DateTimeField
    EndTime = models.DateTimeField

    class Meta:
                verbose_name = "Planned IT Maintenance"
                verbose_name_plural = "Planned IT Maintenance"
```

Comment: A `ForeignKey` is probably a better choice here: `Impact = models.ForeignKey(MaintenanceType)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**'ForeignKey'** is the better solution. You can try below code as well.

models.py

```
Impact = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

forms.py

```
class MaintenanceForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MaintenanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Impact'].choices = list(MaintenanceType.objects.values_list('id', 'Type'))


    class Meta:
        model = Maintenance
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't include any new Maintenance types as it would only be called once (providing you could ever get this far)

Comment: That's still not quite right, you need to set choices to a list of tuples, not a queryset. You could use `value_list`, e.g. `self.fields['Impact'].choices = MaintenanceType.objects.all().values_list('Type', 'Type')`.